# regular expression for image tag and its attribute objective c

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, nsregularexpression

I want to implement regular expression.

part of the HTML string will be similar to :

```
<img id="XXXX1" class="drag" src="doc/XXXX.png" alt="Document not found." height="1056" width="816" border="0" style="border: solid 1px; padding: 10px 0 5px 0;" />
<img class="drag" src="doc/CCTST-DEMO-33919-7002-635974111876372692-02.png" height="1056" width="816" border="0" style="border: solid 1px; padding: 10px 0 5px 0;" /><div><span class="XXXXXX">2 of 2</span></div>
```

regular expression i had implemented is :

```
 NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(<img\\s[\\s\\S]*?src\\s*?=\\s*?['\"](.*?)['\"][\\s\\S]*?>)+?"
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];

    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:data_str
                            options:0
                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [data_str length])
                         usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {

                             NSString *img = [data_str substringWithRange:[result rangeAtIndex:2]];
                             NSLog(@"img src %@",img);
                         }];
```

But i want to implement the condition for img,class and src

Please help

Comment: Its really quite unclear what question you are really asking. Are you asking how to rewire the regular expression or write more code to process the match? Apart from anything else your regex is way more complex than it need be given what it is actually doing.